# Doing HIIT everyday and 3 day workout routine per week in the gym is good for my health?

Tags: running, workout-routines, workout, gym, hiit

I do 20 minutes of minutes and then 20 minutes of stretching every morning.
I go gym for 3 day per gym. As i am a skinny fat guy. I want to remove my belly fat while growing muscle. So this is what i do per week.

Is this good for my health? Or is it good if i continue this routine for 1 year or may be more?

Comment: We need to know more about you - Your age, height, weight, habits, diet, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Doing HIIT every day? I'd do that only every other day - too much of a good thing is a bad thing.

You're not giving your body enough time to rest and recover by doing HIIT every day.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building muscle and doing HIIT, most trainers recommend doing it no more than 3 times a week since HIIT is considered rather strenuous training.

Per [this article](https://muscleevo.net/how-to-avoid-the-fat-trap/) from Muscle Evo:

> Even so, lifting weights and doing HIIT every day is not a great idea.
>   If you want to do HIIT while you focus on building muscle, limit it to
>   1 or 2 short sessions a week.

You may want to find a good trainer to put together a long-term plan that works for your fitness goals.